# MySQL Avg Count With Where and Group By

Tags: mysql, count, average

This table keeps records of calls that salespersons make :

```
id | clientid | salespersonid | call_duration | date | last_update
1  | c2345    | sp34          | 05:00         | yyyy | yyyy
2  | c2345    | sp34          | 05:00         | yyyy | yyyy
3  | c2345    | sp35          | 05:00         | yyyy | yyyy
4  | c2345    | sp36          | 05:00         | yyyy | yyyy
5  | c2361    | sp36          | 05:00         | yyyy | yyyy
6  | c2361    | sp36          | 05:00         | yyyy | yyyy
```

With this table I want to calculate two things :

1. Average of calls per client : The average number of calls made per client.

   In this case number should return : 3
2. Average of calls per salesperson : The average number of calls made per salesperson.

   In this case number should return : 2

Calculating average is pretty much basic math stuff. It's just a matter of counting/adding and dividing by number of rows. But here in MySQL I cant figure out how I would do that without a specific value to provide for the WHERE CLAUSE? I mean if I wanted to calculate average for salesperson 34, I would specify `WHERE salespersonid=sp34`. And if I wanted to calculate average of call for client 2345 I would do `WHERE clientid=c2345` But here I'm wanting to calculate average of average.

Comment: Client c2345 has 4 calls. Client c2361 has 2 calls. The average number of calls per client is (4+2)/2 = 3.

Comment: @Strawberry: Misspelled.

Comment: The average number of calls per salesperson is (2+1+3)/3 = 2

Comment: @Strawberry: I'm tired today. Inverted that.

Comment: @Strawberry: Any query to suggest?

Comment: Show us your effort.

Comment: @FullSTack01: Ah yes I forgot the codes. Be right back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try following queries

for client wise average

> select avg(clientwisecnt.clientidcnt) from ( select clientid,
>   count(clientid) as clientidcnt from t group by clientid    ) as
>   clientwisecnt;

for sales person wise average

> select avg(salespersonwisecnt.salespersoncnt) from ( select
>   salespersonid, count(salespersonid) as salespersoncnt from t group by
>   salespersonid    ) as salespersonwisecnt;

Comment: you can test this queries at this fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/191489/7

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
SELECT COUNT(clientid) / COUNT(DISTINCT(clientid)) AS avg_calls_per_client
FROM calls_table
WHERE {date criteria}

SELECT COUNT(salespersonid) / COUNT(DISTINCT(salespersonid)) AS avg_calls_per_salesperson
FROM calls_table
WHERE {date criteria}
```